# Nested function not work in Mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mozilla

i have call the below function in my application

```
function workerCall() {
    debugger;
    if (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined") {
        var worker = new Worker("Scripts/worker.js");
        worker.onmessage = workerResultReceiver;
        worker.onerror = workerErrorReceiver;
        worker.postMessage({ 'username': Username });
        function workerResultReceiver(e) {
            $('.NotificationCount').html(e.data);
            if (parseInt(e.data) != 0 && currentPage == "Alert") {
                StateFlag = false;
                $('.Notification').show();
                $('.Drildown').each(function () {
                    var temp = this.id;
                    if ($('#' + temp).attr('expand') == "true") {
                        currentTab = temp;
                        StateFlag = true;
                    }
                });
                currentScrollPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
                GetAlerts();
            } else {
                $('.Notification').hide();
            }
        }
        function workerErrorReceiver(e) {
            console.log("there was a problem with the WebWorker within " + e);
        }
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

the method will execute in IE,Chrome but when comes to Mozilla i got an error **ReferenceError: workerResultReceiver is not defined**.How can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are making reference to function that is not created yet. You need to put this:

```
worker.onmessage = workerResultReceiver;
worker.onerror = workerErrorReceiver;
```

Above

```
function workerErrorReceiver
```

line or at the end of the scope.

Comment: Not sure, but can be issue that other browsers didn't call `worker.onmessage` or `onerror` handlers

Comment: @antyrat What you are suggesting? i have already put that in my function

Comment: @JEMI have you tried what I have suggested already? I mean: change function declaration order and attach function after it was declared?

Comment: I have tried.it's working fine..why it is matter in only mozilla?

Comment: @JEMI I suppose this can be reason of realization of ECMA Script in SpiderMonkey. Anyway always better to define functions and variables _before_ you are actually use them. I can't give you 100% answer on this.